# Фильтрация данных из Firebase (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Работаю с Firebase. В ios-приложении необходимо сделать поиск по имени через UISearchController.
Модель данных выглядит примерно так:

```
{
  "users": {
    "Kdkdk2kddjah2ndd": {
      "name": "Johnyy",
      "email": "mymail@mail.org",
    },
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать поиск по полю "name", чтобы можно было искать по первым введенным буквам.
Есть два метода, которые использую для поиска:

```
    let userSearchBarController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    //Массив для найденых пользователей
    var filteredUsers = [User]()


   //Метод для UISearchController, срабатывает при активном SearchBar
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredUsers.removeAll()
        print(userSearchBarController.searchBar.text!)
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: userSearchBarController.searchBar.text!)    
    }

    //Метод запроса нужных пользователей
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {

     if (searchBar != "") {
        FIRDatabase.database()
            .reference()
            .child("users")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
            .queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

                if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    print(snapshot)

                    for key in userDict.keys {

                        if let userData = userDict[key] {
                            //Класс модели User
                            let user = User()

                            let name = userData["name"]
                            let email = userData["email"]

                            user.name = name as? String
                            user.email = email as? String

                            self.filteredUsers.append(user)

                        }

                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }) 
       } 
    }
```

Поиск не работает как надо. Я получаю всех пользователей.
При вводе некоторых букв иногда получаю меньше пользователей, даже если нигде в их полях (userID, name, email) нет такой буквы, не пойму закономерность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитав документацию еще раз, нашел решение. Помогло использование символа Unicode "f8ff".
Часть кода самого запроса:

```
    if (searchText != "") {

        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
        .queryStarting(atValue: searchText)
        .queryEnding(atValue: "\(searchText)\u{f8ff}")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in


     })
```